# Compare Dates in a file

Tags: java

I am having a file which has default date column 1999-09-09 00:00:00, I want to implement a logic if it has default value replace with current system date. If Not compare it with the present date so that if it is less than 60 days do nothing if it is greater than 60 days replace it with again current system date.

```
File f1 = new File("/home/000000_0");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains("1999-09-09 00:00:00")){                     
        line = line.replace("1999-09-09 00:00:00", strDate);
    }
    System.out.println("====="+line);
    lines.add(line);
}
fr.close();
br.close();
```

I am doing the first part and I need to compare Can any one help how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should convert your string to Timestamp and compare two timestamps or then convert the timestamps to Date and compare two Data objects (using methods after(), before(), equals() or so). 
an example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("1999-09-09 00:00:00");
Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime()); //your date as a Timestamp
Date startDate = timestamp; //a Date object
```